# LocalStorage error

Tags: javascript, html

I am **not** able to save the text which is being copied on the button press after reloading the page so that i can remember what i typed before.

**My Code:**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <input type="text" id="txt">
      <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()">
      <p id="p"></p>
      <script>
          function myFunction() {
             document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = document.getElementById('txt').value;

             if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
                 localStorage.setItem("myinputvalue", document.getElementById("p")[0].innerHTML);
                 localStorage.getItem("myinputvalue");
             }
          }   
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to be `document.getElementById("p").innerHTML`. `document.getElementById` does not return `NODE LIST`. So there is no need of `[0]`.

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = document.getElementById('txt').value;

    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        localStorage.setItem("myinputvalue", document.getElementById("p").innerHTML);
        console.log(localStorage.getItem("myinputvalue"))
    }
}
```

Check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/690u3mLw/1/).